# Wepshere profile creation through manageProfiles command

Tags: linux, websphere, websphere-8

I need a Dmgr profile , a federated application server and an application server in Websphere Application Server ND (8.5.5.7).The steps that I followed are

1) **`./manageprofiles.sh -create -profileName Dmgr1 -profilePath "/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr1" -templatePath "/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/management" -serverType DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER -enableAdminSecurity true -adminUserName wasadmin -adminPassword wasadmin`**
This created the Dmgr profile named Dmgr1

2) Then I did this 
**`./manageprofiles.sh -create -profileName Node1 -profilePath "/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Node1" -templatePath "/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/managed" -serverName server1 -federateLater false -dmgrAdminUserName wasadmin -dmgrAdminPassword wasadmin -dmgrHost <host> -dmgrPort <port>`**

This created a Node named Node1 ,but I do not see the application server that I was expecting it would create although I had specified the same in my command **`-serverName server1`**

What command do I need to run (I am not allowed to use the DMGR admin console)so that I get an application server instance inside the federated application server (node) ?

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not need to access the WebSphere Application Server admin console to create the cell you're describing.  You can start the Profile Management Tool (PMT) GUI, press the Create button and select the Cell option.  If you don't have access to PMT, you can still use the commandline tool, manageProfiles.[sh|bat]. Because the syntax for manageProfiles can get tricky, it is often easier to look at the command line PMT creates when executing the Cell creation mentioned above. PMT logs are located at /logs/manageprofiles/pmt.log.
To create Dmgr:

> c:\wasND8559\binmanageprofiles.bat -create -profileName Dmgr01 -enableAdminSecurity false -cellName MyCell01 -nodeName MyCellManager01 -profilePath C:\wasND8559\profiles\Dmgr01 -nodeProfilePath C:\wasND8559\profiles\AppSrv01 -appServerNodeName MyNode01 -templatePath C:\wasND8559\profileTemplates\cell\dmgr

To create and federate App Server:

> c:\wasND8559\bin>manageprofiles.bat -create -enableAdminSecurity false
>   -cellName MyCell01 -nodeName MyCellManager01 -profilePath C:\wasND8559\profiles\AppSrv01 -dmgrProfilePath
>   C:\wasND8559\profiles\Dmgr01 -winserviceCheck false -profileName
>   AppSrv01 -appServerNodeName MyNode01 -templatePath
>   C:\wasND8559\profileTemplates\cell\default

Answer (score 1):

The second step that you have executed, creates a Custom Profile. To quote [IBM Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tpro_instancesmngdnode.html):

> The node within the profile is empty until you federate the node and use the deployment manager to customize the node.

On the federated node, you have to create an Application Server. As you don't have access to the Administrative Console, you can accomplish this using the wsadmin tool. See [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/txml_createserver.html) for the instructions. Alternatively, you can use the `AdminServerManagement` script library for Jython, using the information provided [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/rxml_7libserver1.html).